# How do I categorize a selected image from iOS library using the Xcode picker? (is there a way to add custom parameters to the picker function?)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, uikit

I'm working on a closet-organizing iOS app. The user can click on a menu, which will give them a set of options as to what type of item they want to upload a photo of. For example if they click on the "tops" menu option, the program should be able to upload a photo and put it in a "tops" folder. (I've labeled where it should be changed below) Everything is running fine so far, but I'm having trouble passing through the upload type to the picker function, so everything just gets put into one folder. Is there a way to customize the picker function so that I can include an extra parameter (the category type)?

Here's the code so far:

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//

import UIKit
import PhotosUI
import Photos
import CoreData
import Foundation
import SwiftUI


// user images below
var imageIDs = [String]()
var countImage = 0


class ViewController: UIViewController, PHPickerViewControllerDelegate {

    // when trash is pressed in ClosetDetailViewController, return to ViewController
    @IBAction func unwindToCloset(segue: UIStoryboardSegue) {
        
    }
    
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    
    // CLOSET FOLDER NAME: "closet_folder"
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        
        // popup menu items
        let tops = UIAction(title: "tops") { (action) in
              print("tops!")
            self.addPhotos(categoryType: "tops")
         }
        
         let outerwear = UIAction(title: "outerwear") { (action) in
             print("outerwear!")
             self.addPhotos(categoryType: "outerwear")
         }
        
         let bottoms = UIAction(title: "bottoms") { (action) in
              print("bottoms!")
             self.addPhotos(categoryType: "bottoms")
         }

        let singles = UIAction(title: "one pieces") { (action) in
             print("singles!")
            self.addPhotos(categoryType: "singles")
        }
        
        let accessories = UIAction(title: "accessories") { (action) in
             print("accessories!")
            self.addPhotos(categoryType: "accessories")
        }
        
        let shoes = UIAction(title: "shoes") { (action) in
             print("shoes!")
            self.addPhotos(categoryType: "shoes")
        }
        
        let menu = UIMenu(title: "my closet", options: .displayInline,
                           children: [tops , outerwear , bottoms, singles, shoes, accessories])
        
        // set up collection in closet
        // navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(addPhotos))
        
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [UIBarButtonItem(systemItem: .add, menu: menu)]
        
        collectionView.register(ClosetCollectionViewCell.nib(), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "ClosetCollectionViewCell")
        
        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        let layout = UICollectionViewFlowLayout()
        layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 75, height: 100)
        collectionView.collectionViewLayout = layout
        
        // layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0
        layout.minimumLineSpacing = 15
        collectionView.reloadData()
    }
    
    
    // access photo library
    @objc private func addPhotos(categoryType: String) {
        var config = PHPickerConfiguration()
        config.selectionLimit = 10
        config.filter = .images
        let vc = PHPickerViewController(configuration: config)
        vc.delegate = self
        present(vc, animated: true)
    }
    
    func picker(_ picker: PHPickerViewController, didFinishPicking results: [PHPickerResult]) {
        picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        let group = DispatchGroup()
        results.forEach { result in
            group.enter()
            result.itemProvider.loadObject(ofClass: UIImage.self) { reading, error in
                defer {
                    group.leave()
                }
                guard let image = reading as? UIImage, error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                
                countImage += 1
                print(countImage)
                
                imageIDs.append(String(countImage))
                print(imageIDs)
                

// FOLDER NAME SHOULD BE CHANGED HERE BASED ON CATEGORY TYPE
                LocalFileManager.instance.saveImage(image: image, imageName: String(countImage), folderName: "closet_folder")
            }
        }
        
        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    

    
}


extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegate {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        collectionView.deselectItem(at: indexPath, animated: true)
        print("you tapped me!")
        // set closetImageName in ClosetDetailViewController
        detailImageName = imageIDs[indexPath.row]
        
        print(imageIDs[indexPath.row])
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "closetDetail", sender: nil)
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDataSource {
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // how many cells are shown? based on number of items the user uploaded
        return countImage
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        // return cell for given item
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "ClosetCollectionViewCell", for: indexPath) as! ClosetCollectionViewCell
        
        // show every cell in image array
        cell.imageView.image = LocalFileManager.instance.getImage(imageName: imageIDs[indexPath.row], folderName: "closet_folder")
        
        return cell
    }
}

extension ViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    // margin of padding between cells
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 75, height: 100)
    }
    
}
```

Thanks all!